# glOrtho equivalent to VBO's

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to port a `ClickTeam Fusion` game to `Java` using `LWJGL`. I decided to simply use pixel measurements as everything in this game is done using `PNG` files, even animations (Yes, really). And I have heard of the function called `glOrtho()` which is supposed to let you set how things are drawn in `OpenGL`.

While I managed to get this working with functions like `glVertexf()`, those functions including `glOrtho()` are deprecated and if I am correct completely removed in `OpenGL 3.1`. So, I am using the modern way of doing it which is using `VBO's, Indices, Shaders`, etc. Is there any way to accomplish `glOrtho()`'s effect using a `VBO`?

If you need me to, I can upload the current code I have here as well; just leave a comment and I will update the post with the current code I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For OpenGL >= 3.1 you need to define your own matrices. There are some libs that defined them for you. GLM, to name a famous one.

glOrtho matrix defintion can be found here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml

glOrtho is not an "effect", but a way to project things onto the screen. Ortho refers to "orthogonal", which means "no perspective".

Answer (score 0):

Your projection matrix (`glOrtho`) should be calculated separately from your VBO data. The entire fixed-function stack was removed from the core profile (including `glVertexf` and whatnot), so you should be doing your own matrix math and sending a projection matrix with an orthographic projection to a shader you wrote as a shader uniform.

LWJGL had a Matrix4f class that made life a little easier, last I checked it was gone without a replacement in LWJGL 3.0 but things could have changed since then. There are a handful of other libraries that are meant to be a replacement.

Either way, you should be able to find an implementation of glOrtho online. Here's the first one that came up for me with LWJGL: https://github.com/SilverTiger/lwjgl3-tutorial/blob/master/src/silvertiger/tutorial/lwjgl/math/Matrix4f.java

Relevant function in case you decide to roll your own:

```
public static Matrix4f orthographic(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far) {
    Matrix4f ortho = new Matrix4f();

    float tx = -(right + left) / (right - left);
    float ty = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    float tz = -(far + near) / (far - near);

    ortho.m00 = 2f / (right - left);
    ortho.m11 = 2f / (top - bottom);
    ortho.m22 = -2f / (far - near);
    ortho.m03 = tx;
    ortho.m13 = ty;
    ortho.m23 = tz;

    return ortho;
}
```